# Is DDH hard over this group?

Tags: hardness-assumptions

I'm new to DDH. 
Reading [this survey](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/DDH.pdf), I noticed that DDH is (believed to be) hard in many groups, but most of them are prime-order groups (the only one that is not is the cyclic subgroup of order $(p-1)(q-1)$ of the group of integers modulo $N = pq$).
My question is about the hardness of DDH in this specific composite-order group:

> Let $q$ be a prime such that $p = 4q+1$ is a prime. Is DDH hard in the subgroup of order $2q$ of $\Bbb Z_{p}^\ast$?

---

<sub>Note about this group: My algebra background is fairly basic and I don't even know if this group is guaranteed to exist, and if so, if it guaranteed to be cyclic.</sub>

Comment: Such a group does exist!  Here is the smallest example: $q = 3, p = 4q + 1 = 13$, and the subgroup of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ generated by $10$ has order $2q = 6$.  If you're not sure whether it is cyclic, I recommend reviewing your group theory textbook!

Comment: Nit: the group $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ for $n = pq$ does have order $(p-1)(q-1)$, but if both $p, q$ are odd, it is not cyclic, as it will always have the noncyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ as a subgroup

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Thanks for your example! Just a question: do you mean that this subgroup *always* exists, no matter the choice of $p$ and $q$ (as long as they are both primes)? Also, if that's the case, I don't see why the group must be cyclic, since it has a composite order. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Cristina I was just giving _an example_ of a group satisfying all your criteria (except for the DDH part, since obviously it's too small).  Under what circumstances is $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$ cyclic, for any integer $n$?  How is it related to $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ for prime $p$  What does the Chinese remainder theorem tell you?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Yep! Thanks for the reminder :) I just checked my book and it makes more sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is DDH hard in the subgroup of order $2q$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$

No, it is not.

If you define the function $F(x) = x^{q} \bmod p$, then for any $x$ is\n the group of order $2q$, we have $F(x)= 1$ if $x$ is a member of the proper subgroup of order $q$, and $-1$ if it is not.  And, exactly half of the elements will be in that subgroup.

You will always have an even number (either 0 or 2) of $F(g^a)$, $F(g^b)$, $F(g^{ab})$ be -1; if you find that an odd number of $F(g^a)$, $F(g^b)$, $F(g^c)$ be -1, then you have determined that is *not* a DH triple.

This logic applies to any group that has an order with a small factor.

Comment: That's a great explanation! Thanks a lot, it's much clearer now